# Whenever I press the play button, console gives me a "can't read property of 'play' of null"

Tags: javascript

It is supposed to change the play icon into a pause icon, or vise versa. Here is my code.

```
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector(".song");
  const play = document.querySelector(".play");
  const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
  const video = document.querySelector("vid-container video");

  //Sounds
  const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");

  //Time Display
  const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");

  //Get Length of Outline
  const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();

  //Duration
  let fakeDuration = 600;

  outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength;
  outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;

  //play sound
  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  //Create a function specific to stop and play the sounds
  const checkPlaying = (song) => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      video.play();
      play.src = "./meditation-app-master/svg/play.svg";
    } else {
      song.pause();
      video.pause();
      play.src = "./meditation-app-master/svg/play.svg";
    }
  };
};

app();
```

I really have no idea what is going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ensure your `app()` function is called only **after** the DOM (and your `<video>` element) has loaded. Use `DOMContentLoaded` for this.

Comment: i'm sorry, how are we supposed to know what is causing the error if you show us only half of the page? we need the HTML

Comment: Your selector `'vid-container'` is looking for an element `<vid-container></vid-container>` which in my best guess doesn't exist....is that an id or a class? Much easier to help when you provide enough html also for a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```js
const video = document.querySelector("vid-container video")
```

this selector returns `null` and when you try to execute `video.play()` it raise an error

replace `vid-container video` with the correct selector (add the appropriate selector prefix a `.` for a class selector, or `#` for an id selector)

Comment: There's no need for an extra `class` or `id` selector. The current selector should work as well but the selector path just need to be fixed.

Comment: I didnt mean he should add a class or id I meant he should add a `.` if `vid-container` is a class >> `.vid-container`  or a `#` if `vid-container` is an  id >> `#vid-container`

Comment: *add the appropriate selector prefix* would make it clearer